# How to display stereographic images to VR headset using Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I have loads of .jpeg image files that needs to be displayed into the left and right eye screens of a VR headset that would create a 3D image look. I am someone new to developing AR/VR and am confused as to how I would do that? I believe creating a simple game in Unity automatically displays a stereo image to the user; however, how would I take two 2D images and display it as 3D to the VR headset user?

edit:
I believe the left and right images will have to go separately into each lens, to accomplish this; how would I do this if this is correct if otherwise how else?